# Eclipse: How do I pin the Search View by default?

Tags: eclipse

I do a lot of searches in Eclipse and I have to pin my new searches every time. Is there any way to have my Search View with Pin button pressed by default?

Comment: what do you mean by pin?

Comment: @mosaad if you perform searches in Eclipse, the new Search will replace previous Search unless you pin the Search View (press 'Pin' button). What I need - is to have this Pin button pressed by default (so, I don't need to press it again and again)

Comment: @rmflow Nice question but I don't think there's any such functionality in eclipse.

Comment: Oh, I'm with rmflow. What I want it to do is to keep the Search view up. If you use the up/dn arrows to walk through search results, the whole Search view disappears for no good reason at all. It Just Disappears.

Comment: And eight years later, the eclipse UI is still the same mess. And it wasn't any worse in 2008 either...

Answer (score 0):

Since the pin button does not work. What you can do is restore the windows where "Search" tab appears!!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL6Hj.jpg]